# Chrome extension doesn't display published program

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPSA9.png)

I'm Chrome extension programmer and published first program at last year. Recently, in chrome web store does not display my program called airdesk. It's really weird because this is searched on google. But in chrome webstore, this can't be searched.([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/airdesk))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpqtT.jpg)

As you can see, this is published state and searched on Google.

To solve this, I've send email to Google but they didn't anwser. In fact, Google hasn't email contact service for Chrome web store. I don't know how to contact to Google or their Help center.

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: @HelloWorld Of course, but stackoverflow always asked for programming issue?

Comment: And there doesn't seem to be a problem. Your extension is published and can be found in web store.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/airdesk

Comment: @HelloWorld 
Can I ask if there is an answer that programmers already know?

Comment: @JayA.Little My browser and other computers does not display my program. Can I see your screenshot?

Comment: @SangHunHan - Yes stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JayA.Little I can't see it. https://imgur.com/a/KckdDWJ

Comment: Must be regional then? Here's my view, from Thailand, in Chrome: https://imgur.com/a/KQI4ItI

Comment: @JayA.Little Thank for screenshot. I think it relative to location on manifest.

Comment: @HelloWorld The fact that it appears in some location problem related to the manifest.json file or locale file. If the solution is to modify the locale file and so on, it's a programming problem.
Why do you assume it's not a programming problem?